# Bootstrap: Prevent Bootstrap daterangepicker to set date automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, daterangepicker

I'm having a fully functional jQuery Fullcalendar daterangepicker displayed.

My problem is that today's date is set (in the input field) automatically on load of page, disregarding the field's state - no matter if it already has value sent from server or is yet not set.

How do I prevent daterangepicker from setting a value (by it self) in the input field before the user has clicked any date?

However, in my fullcalendar, i have the following code which does not produce any impact in my screen now..

```
$("event_start_date").datepicker().find(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
```

and also i tried the following:

```
$("#event_start_date").datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Thanks In Advance..!

Comment: Can you show your code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Ryan89 I have added a fiddle here, without adding the datepicker's external sources as i do not know how to 'add'..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Keynes105/h8gn159a/

Comment: You add external resources with the "External Resources" on the left. When you have a JSFiddle that can replicate your problem let me know, or post another question. I check the fullcalendar tag often.

Answer (score 1):

use icon trigger with datetime picker

[jQuery datetime picker with icon](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)
, this will help you to do so

Comment: can you add me a fiddle ?